# Google Play Books unable to save margin note

Tags: annotations, google-play-books

I just bought a new eBook a few moments ago and I went to mark a note for when I began reading it, something I've been in the habit of for many years.

I go to save it and there's a problem without any description for what went wrong. It reads...
"Oops! There was a problem saving your margin note."

Anyone have any ideas how to go about debugging this?

[image: error saving margin note]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my Ghostery browser extension was messing with the site. I was able to pause it and reattempt and found the notes made their way through. I drilled down into the trackers that were blocked, one was "Site Analytics: Google Analytics" another was "Advertising: Technorati". It was the Technorati tracker that was required for the GPB notes features to operate.

It's a little disconcerting to see advertisements in the mix of GPB. Anyone know what the deal with that is?
[image]